# Handling non objects

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I might have a controller function like so

```
public function index()
{
    $poll = DB::table('poll')->whereNull('deleted_at')->orderBy('id', 'desc')->first();
    $question = DB::table('poll_question')->whereNull('deleted_at')->where('poll_id', $poll->id)->first();
    $answers = DB::table('poll_answer')->whereNull('deleted_at')->where('question_id', $question->id)->orderBy('id')->get();

    return view('index', compact('poll', 'question', 'answers'));
}
```

This is fine if the three collections I am obtaining contain data.  If they dont and I try to visit the index page, I get
ErrorException in PollResponseController.php line 20: Trying to get property of non-object

So what is the best way to handle non-object's?  To bypass this, I could do

```
public function index()
{
    $poll = DB::table('poll')->whereNull('deleted_at')->orderBy('id', 'desc')->first();
    if($poll) {
        $question = DB::table('poll_question')->whereNull('deleted_at')->where('poll_id', $poll->id)->first();
        if($question) {
            $answers = DB::table('poll_answer')->whereNull('deleted_at')->where('question_id', $question->id)->orderBy('id')->get();
            return view('index', compact('poll', 'question', 'answers'));
        }
    }

    return view('error');
}
```

But is that not a bit exessive?  I was just wondering if there was a better approach to handling this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use simple `if($question)` clause or `if(is_null($question))`.

```
$question = DB::table('poll_question')->whereNull('deleted_at')->where('poll_id', $poll->id)->first();
if($question){
    // The object is not empty, so I'll use it
}else{
    // The object is empty
}
```

In a blade template it will look like `@if($question)` and `@if(is_null($question))` respectively.

```
@if($question)
    {{ $question->property }}
@endif
```

In most cases you should just bypass all variables in a template and then check each of them with `@if` clauses.